# Removing dynamically created textboxes

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an add user button which adds a textbox and a button.  I want it so that  the new button removes the user it added. My problem is I don't know how to get a dynamically added button to delete dynamically created textboxes...  I think its a problem with how I defined the variables but I don't know what . Here's what I have:

```
    private void AddUserbtn_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox[] Alias = new TextBox[n];

        Button[] Remove = new Button[n];

        int AliasX, AliasY, RemoveX, RemoveY;

        AliasX = 40;
        AliasY = 45;

        RemoveX = 946;
        RemoveY = 45;


        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            Alias[i] = new TextBox();
            Alias[i].Size = new Size(233, 26);
            Alias[i].Location = new Point(AliasX, AliasY + space);
            Alias[i].Font = new Font("Arial", 10);

            Remove[i] = new Button();
            Remove[i].Location = new Point(RemoveX, RemoveY + space);
            Remove[i].Text = "";
            Remove[i].Font = new Font("Arial", 10);
            Remove[i].FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
            Remove[i].BackgroundImage =Properties.Resources.btn_remove_user;
            Remove[i].FlatAppearance.BorderColor = Color.White;
            Remove[i].BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Center;
            Remove[i].Size = new Size(95, 23);
            Remove[i].UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            Remove[i].Click += new EventHandler(Remove_Click);

            space += 35;
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            Panel.Controls.Add(Alias[i]);

        }

        //for(int i=0; i <n;i++)
        //Remove[i].Click += delegate
        //{
        //    Panel.Controls.Remove(Alias[i]);
        //};



    }

    private void Remove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //    Button Remove = sender as Button;

        //    //TextBox[] Alias = new TextBox[n];
        //    //for (int i = 0; i <n; i++)
        //    //{
        //    //    Panel.Controls.Remove(Alias[i]);



        //    //}
    }
```

Comment: Set Id property to your controls, and, how you know which control(s) you want to delete? I think you need add more information in your question.

Comment: The TextBox and Button should probably be in a UserControl.

Comment: When i click the remove button the remove button and alias textbox should delete

Comment: There are many ways to do what you want. For instance, store the associated `TextBox` in the `Button.Tag` property.

Comment: Your code isn't adding the buttons to the panel.  If you are going to do this your way, you would have to use that `i` value in the control's Name or Tag property in order to find it again.  Removing a control does not dispose of it.  Make sure you Dispose of it, which will remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your objects meaningful names like:

```
Alias[i].Name = "UserTextBox" + i;
Remove[i].Name = "UserButton" + i;
```

This way you can find the object to be excluded.

```
Panel.Controls.Remove(Panel.Controls["UserTextBox" + i]);
Panel.Controls.Remove(Panel.Controls["UserButton" + i]);
```